# How to hash the password in the DATABASE_URL with Prisma ORM so that it does not appear visible for all

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

Here is my .env file where I have my database URL with my password visible

[image]

I use this DATABASE_URL in the schema.prisma file for the connection

[image]

I want to hash my password in the database_url and decrypt it for establish connection. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Prisma. The `env()` function only reads the given environment variable as is.

I might ask why you want to do this. Your `DATABASE_URL` should only be read from the secure context of your application server, so encryption is typically unnecessary.

Comment: I want to do this, because I don't want the password to be hardcoded in the source code.